# Sqlite Database Optimization, replacing deleted entries

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a database in android for my App with columns ID, channels, name
I can create fine and everything works.
My ids are attached to commands specific to that channel.
When I have 15 channels and I go to delete channel 4, it creates channel 16 instead of replacing channel 4 first.

Is there a method that I can use that would search for "empty" RowIds first before adding the values?

Answer (score 0):

If the ID column is Auto-Increment then you can't replace 4. The column value is advancing by 1 with each insert.

you can remove the auto-increment take care of the IDs your self.  but for that you'll have to search for the missing number in each insert (not very efficient). maybe you can also save the deleted IDs in some auxiliary table. That can help you avoid the lookup. But not sure if it's worth it...

Comment: there any kinda array I could create to keep up with the ids?

Comment: you can have a deletedIds array/table. Each time you delete, insert the deleted id to that array. When you insert a new channel, select the minimum value from this array and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

a row will be updated if a unique constraint violation occurs for the insert. So the ID column in your example would need to have a PRIMARY KEY constraint in the database schema for the row to be updated

```
contentValue c;
SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
db.replace("table_name", null, c);
```

Comment: ill check this, if it works, ill just set up like 5 variables for the Ids to save up to 5 ids in that need to be replaced, its messy but if it works....

Comment: set up properly the variable c and you won't hava problems.